# How to get the phone Object in Oreo Aosp Code

Tags: android, android-source, core-telephony

I want to write Api for getdataroaming method which is already there in Aosp.

Just now I have written code like this.

```
ContentResolver cr=mPhone.getContext().getContentResolver();
if (Settings.Secure.getInt(cr.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.DATA_ROAMING) == 1) {
    //Data Roaming Enabled      
    flag = true;
} else {
    // Data Roaming Disabled
    flag = false;
}
```

how to get the phone object in separate  java file.
if I used the context.
From where i will get this context?